# php preg_match validate price format

Tags: php

I'd like to validate a numeric field (price) in my form.
I try in this way to validate format like `10.00` and it's ok.

```
$pattern = '/^\d+(:?[.]\d{2})$/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $_POST['price']) == '0') {
   echo "ERROR";
   exit;
}
```

Now I'd like to validate, **at the same time**, the field format like `10.00` and `10`.
How could I do this?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nY0fV0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your new pattern:

```
$pattern = '/^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/';
```

will validate:

```
10
10.00
```

If you want to *invalidate* zero-leading numerics such as 05.00, the following pattern will help:

```
$pattern = '/^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d{2})?$/';
```

Comment: For those who want database `DECIMAL(10,4)` validation: `/^\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{1,4})?$/`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only checking if it's a number, is_numeric() is much much better here. It's more readable and a bit quicker than regex.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly spun up a function for checking if a string or int is a valid price and if not, converting it. The final output is always going to be a string with two digits after the decimal, like `1000.00`.

It removes minus/negative signs, commas, spaces, and dollar signs. The only except is when if the string contains any characters like letters that would set [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to false.

Here is the function:

```
function convertToValidPrice($price) {
    $price = str_replace(['-', ',', '$', ' '], '', $price);
    if(!is_numeric($price)) {
        $price = null;
    } else {
        if(strpos($price, '.') !== false) {
            $dollarExplode = explode('.', $price);
            $dollar = $dollarExplode[0];
            $cents = $dollarExplode[1];
            if(strlen($cents) === 0) {
                $cents = '00';
            } elseif(strlen($cents) === 1) {
                $cents = $cents.'0';
            } elseif(strlen($cents) > 2) {
                $cents = substr($cents, 0, 2);
            }
            $price = $dollar.'.'.$cents;
        } else {
            $cents = '00';
            $price = $price.'.'.$cents;
        }
    }

    return $price;
}
```

And here is to test it:

```
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100'));          // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('-100'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice(100));            // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('$100'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.98'));       // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.9'));        // 100.90
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('1,00.98'));      // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('1,000.98'));     // 1000.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.98829382')); // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('abc'));          // null
```